# Is it possible to pass a reference to a pointer from Excel VBA to C++?

Tags: c++, vba, pointers, excel

I would like to call my own C++ dll function from excel vba:

```
void my_cpp_fun ( int& n_size, double*& my_array);
```

The C++ function creates an array my_array of variable size n_size (this size is computed within my_cpp_fun).

Can I interface this function as is to VBA without using any Excel specific stuff in my C++ code?

So basically what I am looking for is a VBA Declare statement like

```
Declare Sub my_cpp_fun Lib "my_cpp.dll" (n_size As Long, Ref_to_Ptr_Qualifier my_array As Double)
```

An additional problem that just occured to me: If I allocate memory inside the c++ dll using new, will that memory be available once the dll function returns control to VB? If that is not the case, the above is pointless...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it is possible (and easier than the COM route, in my opinion) to call functions in a DLL from VBA. In my experience, the best way to go is to write wrapper functions with `C` linkage (to avoid running into various C++ name-mangling schemes) and exposing an interface of pointers rather than references (as the appropriate VBA type to declare a reference argument or result will be rather difficult to predict).

A great guide for how to write appropriate `Declare` statements (assuming 32-bit Windows) is Chapter 2 of the book "Hardcore Visual Basic", if you can find it.

Note also that any functions exposed to VBA via `Declare` statements will need to use stdcall (aka WINAPI) calling convention.

TLDR:

I'd do this:

```
extern 'C' {
    void WINAPI my_cpp_fun_wrapper ( int *n_size, double **my_array )
    { 
        my_cpp_fun(*n_size, *my_array); 
    } 
}
```

and then

`Declare Sub my_cpp_fun_wrapper Lib "my_cpp.dll" (ptr_n_size As Long, ptr_ptr_my_array As Long)`

and use the various `*Ptr` functions of VB6/VBA to get the pointers to my data.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create a COM object that exposes your function and load it in your VBA using [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220083%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: So it is not possible without using the Excel API?I was thinking of something simple like 
Declare Sub my_cpp_fun Lib "my_cpp.dll" (n_size As Long, Magic_Ref_to_ptr_qualifier my_array As Double)

Comment: It is possible, but it is way more trouble than its worth to go that route.  It is far easier to have a COM dll wrap your raw dll when interfacing with VB.

Comment: No, Declare is easier than COM if the interface's surface area is small. COM is a royal pain in the backside, especially from C++.

Comment: @David:  What you have to do to make it work properly with VBA is essentially everything under the hood of a basic COM dll (C-linkage, pointers to arrays, etc).  If you are using VS, creating a basic wrapper COM DLL takes all of 4 mouse clicks, and all of the crap you'd have to go through to get the raw dll to work is done for you.

Comment: @Zac: figuring out which mouseclicks to use even when you have some experience with those crappy tools takes you a very long time and a lot of head bangs.

Comment: Might be wrong, but I thought part of the problem with adding a COM interface to your C++ class/s was not just the initial coding/use of templates, but the headache of versioning/updating/deploying the C++ project as time goes on.

Comment: In this case, I wouldn't add a COM interface to his class; I'd create a separate COM interface that wraps the function calls to his class.  Versioning in COM is very straight forward, and you only use templates if you use ATL (which isn't necessary; COM can be written in C if desired).